# jquery NaN on average

Tags: jquery, nan

I trying to get a review average. The first part of the jQuery is for progress bar animation and the second part is for getting the review average. However my `console.log` gives me `NaN` and I don't know why.

```js
var avg = 0;
var amount = 0;

$(".review").each(function() {
  var progres = $(".progress-bar");
  progres.each(function() {
    avg = avg + parseInt($(".aria-valuenow").text());
    amount = amount + 1;
  });
});

avg = avg / amount;
console.log(avg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review">
  <span class="progressText"><B>review 1</B></span>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar w-75" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="progressText"><B>review 2</B></span>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar w-75" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="35" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="avg"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You have no elements with a class of `.aria-valuenow`. You can also achieve what you require in a single `each()` loop

Comment: Your `.each()` loop isn't using the elements that it's looping over.

Comment: You have too many loops all through this code

Comment: This really isn't related to jQuery at all.   Had you extracted out this expression `$(".aria-valuenow").text()` and assigned it to a variable and `console.log`ged it, you would have found the issue on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping over all the progress bars, but not adding up anything from that progress bar -- the callback function never uses `this` to get the current element. Instead, it's getting the text of an element with `class="aria-valuenow"`; that's not a class, it's an attribute of the progress bar DIV.

I think what you want is:

```
avg += parseInt($(this).attr("aria-valuenow"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the line:

```
 avg=avg+parseInt($(".aria-valuenow").text());
```

wouldn't work because your that statement means to **get the text from the elements with aria-valuenow class** while you actually `aria-valuenow` is a property. So that line should look like the following:

```
 avg += Number($(".progress-bar").prop("aria-valuenow"));
```

The reason you are getting `NaN` (the value representing **NotANumber**) is because said line is expanded to the following:

```
avg += parseInt("")
```

And `parseInt("")` result in `NaN` as well as any further sum to it (`NaN + 1 = NaN`)